# Sqlite UNION ALL Query with Different Columns

Tags: sqlite

Using `UNION ALL` with Queries with **different number of column** returns the following error `sqlite3.OperationalError: SELECTs to the left and right of UNION ALL do not have the same number of result columns`.
I tried
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704450/union-all-with-queries-that-have-a-different-number-of-columns) answer but I think that is now outdated and does not work. I tried to find something in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) but I couldn't find it.
Both `UNION` and `UNION ALL` do not work.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597727/merging-queries-with-different-columns) answer is a bit complex for me to understand.

What would be the workaround to achieve this? A Column with `Null` - how do I do that ?

Update:

Also, I don't know the no. or name of tables as in my program I allow the user to create and manipulate data.
To find out the queries in the database, I Use:

```sql
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

and to find out the columns I use this:

```sql
[i[0] for i in cursor.description]
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, the column size and type for each side of a union must be identical.

You can make them identical by casting columns to the correct type, or setting missing columns to NULL.

Comment: One Problem, I don't know the Name of Tables and Columns as in my program they are created and defined by the user. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to compensate for the missing columns with adding 'empty' columns.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table1(k INTEGER, v INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE test_table2(k INTEGER);

INSERT INTO test_table1(k,v) VALUES(4, 5);
INSERT INTO test_table2(k) VALUES(4);

SELECT * FROM test_table1 UNION ALL SELECT *,'N/A' FROM test_table2;
4|5
4|N/A
```

Here I've added another pseudo-column with 'N/A', so the `test_table2` has two columns before the UNION ALL happens.

Comment: One Problem, I don't know the Name of Tables and Columns as in my program they are created and defined by the user. I updated the question.